# My tkinter app wont start on armbian startup

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, orange-pi, armbian

I have orangepi lite card and armbian in it. I have pyhon tkinter app that needs to start at boot so i write sh file for it.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /folder-to-main-script
sudo python3 PinReader.py

#for the test purposes
echo "insertedtext" > file.txt
```

Here is my startup.sh when triggered from terminal it works perfectly.
Then i added a .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyAppName
Exec=bash /full/path/to/working/directory/startup.sh
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

It start the script on startup for sure but not the app. How can i start the tkinter program on startup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is we cant sudo on startup. We have to give

```
chmod 7445 /usr/bin/python3
```

Then we can start it on startup.

Also we can add

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

to our python script so it runs when we call it like

```
/path_to_mainfile/mainfile.py
```

We dont need to use sh file we can change the autostart file to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyAppName
Exec=/path_to_mainfile/mainfile.py
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

it'll work.